# Cloud Page with SmartCapture to serve as preference center and/or unsubscribe page

Tags: marketing-cloud, smart-capture, unsubscribe

I have 2 questions:

1. In an email template, can we set up in the footer section a single one-click-to-unsubscribe link, which would serve as Master Unsubscribe at the BU level?
2. Can we set up a Cloud Page with a SmartCapture form to serve as a preference center? Can the latter be set up without using gazillions of lines of AMPscript code?

We're using data extensions for send-outs and the AllSubscribers is most often used as default Publication List. I saw some questions arose on this topic but, honestly, I've been having difficulties comprehending them, let alone implementing them in our SFMC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you are going to have much luck implementing this using a smart capture form on a CloudPage. You are going to have to execute a logUnsubEvent in order to update a subscriber's status within the platform, but the smart capture form is made to capture data and not execute functions on it (without some scripting anyway).

So, in order to accomplish #1 of your question above, you are going to have to code that solution up yourself. Though there is some ampscript involved, it's not actually that complex. Here's [an example script from the SFMC documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/unsubEvent.htm) that should give you all you need to get going. Just pass the fields it's asking for with [the RequestParameter function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm) from you email and the logic of the script should do all the other lifting.

Comment: Tnx. I'll try that way.

Comment: Lol, I received an answer from the SF support saying I could use the SmartCapture form for this. It's a crazy place down at SF...